# Why is associated User information null when queried through a lookup in a test?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an apex class that I am testing that queries for the record Owner information on leads. When I try to access the Owner information the values are null. However, when I query the user object directly the values are populated. This only happens in test execution

**Apex:**

```
//get leads
Map<Id, Lead> leads = new Map<Id, Lead>([
    SELECT Id, Email, Owner.Email, OwnerId
    FROM Lead
    WHERE Id IN :leadIds
]);

//Debug email via lookup
System.debug('lead owner email: ' + leads.values().get(0).Owner.Email);
//debug email via direct query
System.debug('User Email: ' + [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id = :leads.values().get(0).OwnerId].Email);
```

**Debugs:**

```
15:40:42.605 (9825005646)|USER_DEBUG|[148]|DEBUG|lead owner email: null
15:40:42.605 (9825315527)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[149]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
15:40:42.605 (9829377675)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[149]|Rows:1
15:40:42.605 (9829607692)|USER_DEBUG|[149]|DEBUG|User Email: Redacted but is a valid email
```

Comment: Is the get leads your test or your code? Are you sure you created the lead in the test?

Comment: It is code being tested, and yes they are populated otherwise I would be getting an `IndexOutOfBounds` error accessing them in the debugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you're getting this is because the lead owner field is polymorphic. The lead owner can be a user, queue, partner user, etc.

So, as a result, it's easier to run 2 seperate queries or do a join on the user object.

Here's some docs on polymorphic fields - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm

Comment: That is a good theory

Comment: I updated my post @TemporaryFix to include documentation on polymorphic keys... i think that'll do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Your lead is owned by a queue not a user. PartOfTheOhana is right in that it's polymorphic but if the owner was a user your debug would work.

Example:

```
@IsTest
static void methodName()
{
    Profile profId = [Select Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'NPD Standard'];
    String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
    Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
    String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;

    User tuser = new User(
        IsActive = true,
        FirstName = 'Testing',
        LastName = 'User',
        Email = uniqueName + '@dan' + orgId + '.com',
        Username = uniqueName + '@dan' + orgId + '.com',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        ProfileId = profId.Id);
    insert tuser;

    Lead l = new Lead();
        l.OwnerId = userinfo.getUserId();
        l.LastName = 'Dan';
        l.Email = 'dan@dan.com';
        l.Company = 'Dan';
        l.OwnerId = tuser.Id;
    insert l;   

    Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
    leadIds.add(l.Id);

    Map<Id, Lead> leads = new Map<Id, Lead>([
        SELECT Id, Email, Owner.Email, OwnerId
        FROM Lead
        WHERE Id IN :leadIds
    ]);

    System.debug('lead owner email:: ' + leads.values().get(0).Owner.Email);
```

> |DEBUG|lead owner email:: 00d0r0000000gnfeai20191125171821456832@dan00d0r0000000gnfeai.com

If you switch the owner to a queue you get the same results:

```
@IsTest
static void methodName()
{
    Group q = [select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' LIMIT 1];

    Lead l = new Lead();
        l.OwnerId = userinfo.getUserId();
        l.LastName = 'Dan';
        l.Email = 'dan@dan.com';
        l.Company = 'Dan';
        l.OwnerId = q.Id;
    insert l;   

    Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
    leadIds.add(l.Id);

    Map<Id, Lead> leads = new Map<Id, Lead>([
        SELECT Id, Email, Owner.Email, OwnerId
        FROM Lead
        WHERE Id IN :leadIds
    ]);

    System.debug('lead owner email:: ' + leads.values().get(0).Owner.Email);
```

> |DEBUG|lead owner email:: null

Comment: It's not owned by a queue, I am querying the user with the same exact Id and getting the result. Again, if that were not the case, the debug would fail.